# Empty Claims after OpenID and OAuth authorisation using ASP.NET core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, oauth, openid, asp.net-core-2.0, claims

I've migrated already existed project to new core 2.0 [using this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) 
and almost all things are absolutely fine except Authentication with OpenID and OAuth.

OpenID is used for MS auth, and OAuth - for LinkedIn.

It redirects me to MS Login page (or to LinkedIn in the second case) 
and after successful authentication redirects me back to my app but with no credentials at all. 
`User.Claims` in  `AccountController` are still empty after this.

Here is my code in `Startup.cs`:

```
    // in Configure()
    app.UseAuthentication();

    // in ConfigureServices()
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(
                opts =>
                {
                    opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    opts.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    opts.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    opts.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(AddAzureAuthOptions)
            .AddOAuth(Configuration["LinkedIn:AuthenticationScheme"], AddLinkedInAuthOptions);


    private void AddAzureAuthOptions(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        // Azure auth
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"];
        options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    }

    private void AddLinkedInAuthOptions(OAuthOptions options)
    {
        // LinkedIn auth
        options.ClientId = Configuration["LinkedIn:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["LinkedIn:ClientSecret"];

        options.CallbackPath = new PathString(Configuration["LinkedIn:CallbackPath"]);

        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["LinkedIn:AuthorizationEndpoint"];
        options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["LinkedIn:TokenEndpoint"];
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["LinkedIn:UserInformationEndpoint"];

        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async contextLocal => await CreatingTicketHandler(contextLocal)
        };
    }

    private static async Task CreatingTicketHandler(OAuthCreatingTicketContext contextLocal)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
            contextLocal.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
        request.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", contextLocal.AccessToken);
        request.Headers.Add("x-li-format", "json");

        var response = await contextLocal.Backchannel.SendAsync(request,
            contextLocal.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        var userId = user.Value<string>("id");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            contextLocal.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("linkedinid", userId, ClaimValueTypes.String,
                contextLocal.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
        }

        var formattedName = user.Value<string>("formattedName");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formattedName))
        {
            contextLocal.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("firstlastname", formattedName,
                ClaimValueTypes.String, contextLocal.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
        }

        var email = user.Value<string>("emailAddress");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            contextLocal.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("linkedinemail", email, ClaimValueTypes.String,
                contextLocal.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
        }
    }
```

Actions in AccountController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult SignInExternal(string scheme, string uri)
    {
        if (User == null || !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = uri}, scheme);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    } 

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignInExternalCallback(string type, string direct)
    {
        var socialNetwork =
            _socialNetworksService?.GetSocialNetwork(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.EndsWith(type))
                ?.Value);

        // if socialNetwork doesn't exist in DB redirects to external SignUp-s
        if (socialNetwork is null)
            return RedirectToAction(direct);

        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(socialNetwork.User, true);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignUpMicrosoft(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var claims = User.Claims.ToList(); // claims are still empty
        var user = _sessionService.GetCurrentUser();

        if (user is null) // create user in system using passed Claims 
        {
            var firstName = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "givenname")?.Value;
            var lastName = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "surname")?.Value;

            await CreateNewUserViaExternalAccountHelperAsync(User.Identity.Name, firstName, lastName,
                User.Identity.Name, SocialNetworkType.Microsoft, "objectidentifier");
        }
        else // sign in User
        {           
            var id = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "objectidentifier")?.Value;               

            await SingInViaExternalAccountHelper(user, SocialNetworkType.Microsoft, id);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignUpLinkedIn()
    {
        var claims = User.Claims.ToList(); // claims are still empty

        var user = _sessionService.GetCurrentUser();

        var email = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "linkedinemail")?.Value ?? string.Empty;

        if (user is null) // create user in system using passed Claims 
        {
            var userName = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "firstlastname")
                ?.Value
                .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var firstName = userName?.FirstOrDefault();
            var lastName = userName?.LastOrDefault();

            await CreateNewUserViaExternalAccountHelperAsync(email,firstName, lastName, email,
                SocialNetworkType.LinkedIn, "linkedinid");
        }
        else // sign in as User
        {
            var userId = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "linkedinid")?.Value;

            await SingInViaExternalAccountHelper(user, SocialNetworkType.LinkedIn, userId);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    private async Task CreateNewUserViaExternalAccountHelperAsync(string email, string firstName,
        string lastName, string userName,
        SocialNetworkType type, string idType)
    {
        var newUser = new User
        {
            Activated = true,
            Email = email,
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
            Enabled = true,
            UserName = userName
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser));

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(newUser.UserName);

            await SingInViaExternalAccountHelper(currentUser, type,
                User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.EndsWith(idType))?.Value);
        }
    }

    private async Task SingInViaExternalAccountHelper(User user, SocialNetworkType type, string id)
    {
        await _socialNetworksService.CreateSocialNetworkAsync(user, id, type);
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
    }
```

A lot of thanks for any replies.